# Error occurring in sending mail for Forget password

Tags: laravel-5

I have set up laravel 5.6 on server. When I try to use Forget Password, I am gettting error after enter email id:

> Class Swift_AddressEncoder_IdnAddressEncoder does not exist

actually, it was working find two days before but now i dont know what happen...I have done thing in it.

below connection in `.env`:

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
    MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.EcuUbtbhSbq1IAh**1tPQg.uFah8Jw**7lh10wGpA_CPU01ySmAC26HFylz_BFI
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your Trade Log"
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@y**r**r*a**.com
```

this is live link for Reset Password: [YourTradeLog](http://yourtradelog.com/password/reset)

Comment: it seems that you have added the verification classes, which is not available in 5.6 but in 5.7

Comment: its was working fantastic two days before in `laravel 5.6`. @HamzaMohamed

Comment: could be many things .. I'm just noting that it seems to be related to verification, did you add the verification classes? it shall narrow our search area :)

Comment: please tell me what code you want to see? actually i followed tutorial before so long ago. I am not sure about `Verification classes`. I can give you code @HamzaMohamed

Comment: can you show your user traits and if your routes?